# Geometry, mesh manipulation

Tags: python, math, geometry, mesh, fold

I‘m looking for some help regarding a mathematical/geometry topic.
I have a closed surface, which consists of 2 layers on top of each other and i want to fold this surface using a predefined fold pattern (folding angle and fold-axis and fold-direction ) 
Do you know which python module/modules could be used to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to your second question on Stack Overflow. However, asking for a module recommendation is explicitly off-topic for this site. Instead, describe a particular problem and ask how to solve that problem. The solution may be a module or it could be a small program that you write yourself. Please reword your question to make it on-topic.

Comment: Furthermore, this sounds like a highly involved problem, depending on what you are trying to do. You might want to consider some simulation framework, where you represent the object as a volumetric mesh.